# Apache Camel - not moving file

Tags: java, apache-camel

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. I have tried all sorts of things, including absolute paths, relative, enabling logging (which also doesnt seem to be working, using Main, using DefaultCamelContext, adding threadsleep, but I cannot get camel to move a file from one folder to another.

Here is my code:

```
package scratchpad;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.beanio.BeanIODataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;

public class CamelMain {

    private static Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        main = new Main();
        main.addRouteBuilder( new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
//              DataFormat format = new BeanIODataFormat(
//                      "org/apache/camel/dataformat/beanio/mappings.xml",
//                      "orderFile");


                System.out.println("starting route");
                // a route which uses the bean io data format to format a CSV data
                // to java objects
                from("file://input?noop=true&startingDirectoryMustExist=true")
                .to("file://output");               
            }
        });
        //main.run();
        main.start();
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         main.stop();


    }

}
```

Can someone spot anything wrong with the above?

Thanks

Comment: And you have created a directory named `input` as you have told Camel that this directory must exist. And then just put a file in that directory. And Camel copies it to output dir. But you need to do this within 5 seconds as that is your sleep time.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example read from the free chapter 1 for the Camel in Action book, as it has a file copied example it covers from top to bottom.

The pdf can be downloaded here: http://manning.com/ibsen/